# For any strictly increasing convergent sequence $x_n$, the sequence $f(x_n)$ is convergent

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

> Let $f(x)$ be defined on R and be strictly increasing.
>
> Claim: for any strictly increasing convergent sequence $x_n$, the
>   sequence $f(x_n)$ is convergent.

I believe it's false. Think about any strictly increasing **right-continuous** function with a jump discontinuity. Clearly, as $x_n$ goes to the point of discontinuity, $f(x_n)$ fails to converge because at that point the left-sided limit isn't equal to the value of the function.

The problem is that the suggested answer is that the claim is true. Am I right or no?

Comment: $f(x_n)$ does not need to equal the value of $f(\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} x_n)$, it just needs to converge. In your example, it would converge to the left-sided limit (which is less than the function value if the function is discontinuous there).

Comment: $f(x_n)$ is always convergent, but it can happen that the limit does not coincide with $f(x)$, where $x$ is the limit of $x_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An increasing and bounded sequence is convergent. 
Since the sequence $(x_n)_{n\geqslant 1}$ converges, it is bounded by some constant $M$. Since the function $f$ is increasing, we have for each $n$, $f(x_1)\leqslant f(x_n)\leqslant f(x_{n+1})  \leqslant f(M)$, hence the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n\geqslant 1}$ is increasing and bounded.

The claim is true, but indeed, if $f$ is not continuous, we may have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\neq f(\lim_{n\to \infty}x_n)     $.

Comment: So I simply misread the problem! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome.